# javascript regex - whats wrong with my very simple regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate email address in html form. I have very little knowledge in regex.

Validation is very simple, just to match `any_symbols@any_symbols.two_to_eight_symbols` pattern.

Here is the regex I'm trying to use `^.+@.+\..{2,8}$`. Yet it doesn't work, it validates pattern `any_symbols@four_symbols`.

Note: do not worry about such simple validation, on server side I'm doing `filter_var` (php) and sending token to that email. Just need to enable button on form when inputed email address fits some sane pattern :)

**EDIT** Those patterns "any_symbols..." I've mentioned in question are just textual representation of what I'm trying to input. This is not what I type in input field :) Usually I type "test@test.com", or "blabla@hehe.haha" and etc. :)

**EDIT2** Actuall code:

```
   var email_regex = new RegExp("^.+@.+\..{2,8}$");
if ($target.val().match(email_regex) !== null){
    $button.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
}
else{
    $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
}
```

**EDIT3** **Found the problem!** It wasn't the regex itself, it was how I passed regex to Regex function... it should be

```
 new RegExp(/^.+@.+\..{2,8}$/);
```

not the

```
new RegExp("^.+@.+\..{2,8}$");
```

As I've said this whole regex thing is quite new to me :))

Comment: In my browser, `/^.+@.+\..{2,8}$/.test("any_symbols@four_symbols")` is `false` :-?

Comment: Try `'any_symbols@four_symbols'.match('^.+@.+\..{2,8}$');`

Comment: Updated my question. Also according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match "If there were no matches, the method returns `null`.".

Comment: `RegExp(/foo/)` is redundant. The constructor expects a string, thus `/foo/` gets probably casted to `"foo"`. It fixes the problem by pure chance.

Comment: So why does `RegExp(/foo/)` does the trick and `RegExp("foo")` doesn't?

Comment: Because the `\.` in `/\./` is read as `\.`, while the `\.` in `"\."` is read as `.`. The JavaScript parser does not follow the same rules in regexp and string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suposely the regex for a real email address is not quite simple, since it should comply with an RFC standard.

However, if this works for you, I've used it with no problems:

```
// The regex: /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/

// To test it:
var regex = new RegExp(/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/);

if( regex.test( your_string ) ){ ... } // returns true if valid
```

If you  really need to accept ANY symbols, you can use the regex that Birei posted.

Comment: I found the problem myself and it wasn't regex, but I'm accepting your answer, since you gave informative answer and to boost your reputation score ;) Thank you!

Comment: I preferred the original expression. At least, it would accept internationalized domain names (IDN).

Comment: Álvaro, you're right. This one would not accept japanese or any other symbols. I've never thought about it. Thanks for this. Maybe this thread'll work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Not a Javascript expert, but with your definition of `any_symbols@any_symbols.two_to_eight_symbols` I think this could work:

```
^[^@]+@[^.]+\..{2,8}$
```

Comment: it's different than mine regexp, but still matches the same pattern. I mean it also matches `any_symbols@four_symbols` instead of `any_symbols@any_symbos.2_to_8_symbols`

Comment: Sorry, your regex was correct, but I hope you don't mind that I'll accept answer of lu1s, because he has not so much reputation score as you do :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slash:

```
'any_symbols@four_symbols'.match('^.+@.+\\..{2,8}$');
                                        ^^
```

Otherwise, JavaScript reads `\.` as an unknown escape sequence and [ignores the slash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Escaping_characters):

> For characters not listed [...] a preceding backslash is
>   ignored, but this usage is deprecated and should be avoided.

(Damn, this was hard to spot...)